# Pycharm Error importing while the application working

Tags: python, pycharm

I have this directory structure:

```
+--myproject
¦   +--code
¦   ¦    +--models
¦   ¦    ¦     __init__.py
¦   ¦    ¦     m.py
¦   ¦    ¦_
¦   ¦    
¦   ¦    +--resources
¦   ¦    ¦     __init_.py
¦   ¦    ¦     r.py
¦   ¦    ¦_
¦   ¦    
¦   ¦    app.py
¦   ¦    
¦   +--venv
¦   .gitignore
¦   requirements.txt
¦_
```

In `m.py` I have:

```
class M:
  pass
```

and in `r.py` I have:

```
from models.m import M  # HERE IS THE PROBLEM!

class R:
  pass
...
```

and in `app.py`:

```
from resources.r import R
```

Please note that when I want to create the pycharm project, I go to

---

File --> New Project --> choose myprojec directory as location -->

Create project existing sources --> Open the project in a New Window -->

`pip install -r requirements.txt` in pycharm terminal  -->

`cd code` in my pycharm terminal --> run `python app.py`

---

My code is working correctly.

But Pycharm draws a red line under my import. It is giving me a false alarm. I know there should be some setting in Pychram to fix this? What is the fix for this?

Comment: You have to set the correct interpreter for the project in the settings.

Comment: I set the `code` directory to source roots and it solved my problem. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html